# Notifications getting cancelled when app closes

Tags: java, android

I am using Socket.io in my application, and using Broadcast Receiver in my Application Class to see for broadcasts that I did when receiving new updates from Sockets. When I receive the Notification I want to create a Notification.

- I am able to create notification on 8.0 (Oreo)

. When I close the app, the Broadcast receiver will be unregistered, sockets will be disconnected. But the problem is that the notification is also going away when ever the app is closed or in Background

Using the socket connection I am able to create the notifications, but these notifications are getting dismissed/cancelled when the app goes into the background.

I checked the code for **setAutoCancel**, **cancel**, or **cancelAll** and I am not calling them anywhere

Application Class

```
//... Notification Channels
public static final String STATE_SERVICE_ID = "StateChannel";
private final String STATE_SERVICE_NAME = "Change State";

public static final String LIVE_UPDATES_ID = "LiveUpdateChannel";
private final String LIVE_UPDATE_NAME = "Live Updates";

public static final String LIVE_FLIGHTS_ID = "FlightChannel"; //..Channel on which I want to show the notification
private final String LIVE_FLIGHTS_NAME = "Flight Updates";


private NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager;
private NotificationCompat.Builder flightNotification;//.. Will be using this to create a notification


 //.. Creating Notifications in OnCreate() of Application
private void createNotificationChannels() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        NotificationChannel stateChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                STATE_SERVICE_ID,
                STATE_SERVICE_NAME,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
        );

        NotificationChannel updatesChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                LIVE_UPDATES_ID,
                LIVE_UPDATE_NAME,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
        );

        NotificationChannel flightChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                LIVE_FLIGHTS_ID,
                LIVE_FLIGHTS_NAME,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        );

        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        List<NotificationChannel> notificationChannels = new ArrayList<>();
        notificationChannels.add(stateChannel);
        notificationChannels.add(updatesChannel);
        notificationChannels.add(flightChannel);

        assert manager != null;
        manager.createNotificationChannels(notificationChannels);

        notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    }
}

//.. I copied this code from Google Docs
private void createNotificationTypes() {
    flightNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, LIVE_FLIGHTS_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
            .setContentTitle("Flight Updates")
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
}

//... Inner Class for receiving Broadcasts
private class flightReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(String.valueOf(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE).equals(intent.getAction())){
            flightNotification.setContentText("Small Text");
            notificationManager.notify(1, flightNotification.build());
        }

    }
}
```

Expected Results: Notification getting created and it stays there even after the app is closed.

Actual Results: Notification is getting created but as soon as app is closed the notification closes.

**EDIT**

If Someone wants Full File of Application Class.. here it is:

```
    import android.app.Application;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycle;
import android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver;
import android.arch.lifecycle.OnLifecycleEvent;
import android.arch.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwner;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.avileapconnect.com.BuildConfig;
import com.avileapconnect.com.Interfaces.I_NetworkResponse;
import com.avileapconnect.com.NetworkManager;
import com.avileapconnect.com.R;
import com.avileapconnect.com.ServiceLayer.SocketService_Test;
import com.avileapconnect.com.services.ForeSocketService;
import com.avileapconnect.com.services.ForeStateService;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static com.avileapconnect.com.services.ForeSocketService.DUMMY_KEY;

public class LifeCycleObserver extends Application
        implements LifecycleObserver, I_NetworkResponse {

    private String state = "foreground";
    SharedPreferences pref;
    private String Response = "";

    public static final String STATE_SERVICE_ID = "StateChannel";
    private final String STATE_SERVICE_NAME = "Change State";

    public static final String LIVE_UPDATES_ID = "LiveUpdateChannel";
    private final String LIVE_UPDATE_NAME = "Live Updates";

    public static final String LIVE_FLIGHTS_ID = "FlightChannel";
    private final String LIVE_FLIGHTS_NAME = "Flight Updates";

    private NetworkManager networkManager;

    private flightReceiver receiver;
    private NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager;
    private NotificationCompat.Builder flightNotification;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
        pref = getSharedPreferences(Keys.getPreferenceFileName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        networkManager = new NetworkManager(this,this);

        receiver = new flightReceiver();
        createNotificationChannels();
        createNotificationTypes();
    }

    private void createNotificationChannels() {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            NotificationChannel stateChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    STATE_SERVICE_ID,
                    STATE_SERVICE_NAME,
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
            );

            NotificationChannel updatesChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    LIVE_UPDATES_ID,
                    LIVE_UPDATE_NAME,
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
            );

            NotificationChannel flightChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    LIVE_FLIGHTS_ID,
                    LIVE_FLIGHTS_NAME,
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            );



            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            List<NotificationChannel> notificationChannels = new ArrayList<>();
            notificationChannels.add(stateChannel);
            notificationChannels.add(updatesChannel);
            notificationChannels.add(flightChannel);

            assert manager != null;
            manager.createNotificationChannels(notificationChannels);

            notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

        }
    }

    private void createNotificationTypes() {
        flightNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, LIVE_FLIGHTS_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setContentTitle("Flight Updates")
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    void onAppBackgrounded() {
        //App in background
        handleServicesForBackground();

        SocketService_Test.getInstance().disconnectSocket();
        Intent socketIntent = new Intent(this, ForeSocketService.class);
        stopService(socketIntent);

//        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    public void handleServicesForBackground() {
        state = "background";
        if(!pref.getString(Keys.getPreferenceMobileNoKey(),"").equals("")){
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ForeStateService.class);
            serviceIntent.putExtra("inputExtra",state);
            startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    void onAppForegrounded(){
        //App in Foreground
        Log.i("Lifecycle Observer","onStart Called");

        handleServicesForForeground(pref);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(String.valueOf(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID
                + BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE));
        registerReceiver(receiver,filter);
    }

    public void handleServicesForForeground(SharedPreferences pref) {
        String state = "foreground";

        if(!pref.getString(Keys.getPreferenceMobileNoKey(),"").equals("")){
           networkManager.changeState(this.pref.getString(Keys.getPreferenceMobileNoKey(),""),
                   state);

            Intent socketIntent = new Intent(this, ForeSocketService.class);
            startService(socketIntent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void getNetworkSuccessResponse(String TAG, String successResponse, String TAGforApi) { }

    @Override
    public void getNetworkFailResponse(String TAG, VolleyError failResponse, String TAGforApi) { }


    private class flightReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(String.valueOf(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE).equals(intent.getAction())){
//                String content = intent.getStringExtra(DUMMY_KEY);

                flightNotification.setContentText("Small Text");
                notificationManager.notify(1, flightNotification.build());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which device you are using?

Comment: Emulator from Android studio